# How to save a variable value outside of a function in javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, scope

I am newbie to JavaScript, I was trying to make a simple `GoogleMaps` which is centered in my current position and I am finding problems saving my latitude and longitude to center the map.

Here is my code which i have adopted:

```
function initialize() {
 var latitudeCenter;
 var longitudeCenter;
 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
 function onSuccess(position){
 console.log(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
 latitudeCenter = position.coords.latitude;
 longitudeCenter = position.coords.longitude;
 }
 function onError(error){
 alert('Error en GPS: ' + error);
 }
var mapOptions = {
 zoom: 8,
 center: new google.maps.LatLng(latitudeCenter, longitudeCenter)
};
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),mapOptions);
console.log('latitud: ' + latitudeCenter + ' longitud: ' + longitudeCenter);
}
```

In the first console log I can read my current position and latitude, so that method works fine, but when I try to save it in centerLatitude and centerLongitude it does not work, it displays undefined.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the functions `onSuccess` and `onError` are asynchronous, so you won't get back an answer straight away. So therefore you put your actual map initialisation code inside that `onSuccess`

```
function initialize() {
    var latitudeCenter;
    var longitudeCenter;
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);

    function onSuccess(position){
        console.log(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
        latitudeCenter = position.coords.latitude;
        longitudeCenter = position.coords.longitude;

        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 8,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(latitudeCenter, longitudeCenter)
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),mapOptions);
    }

    function onError(error){
        alert('Error en GPS: ' + error);
    }


    console.log('latitud: ' + latitudeCenter + ' longitud: ' + longitudeCenter);
}
```